# Boolean modifier for 3d printing

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing, svg, stl

I have a problem with custom dice for my 3d printer, when I print my numbers are all upside down.  On the other hand, the letters are all in the place, I followed at least 15 guide made 15 tried different and always the same result.  Basically I thought my problem came from my svg files, so I did everything in stl version, and still the same problem, so I made the numbers and letters in curve version and applied mesh to do the boolean operation.

Each dice seems to be perfect on the screen and when I put it in my slicer program, because I tried two slicer software too.  the result remains the same number coming from the inside, totally seems opposite to the model but the letters are ok.

---

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKb6t.png)

[image]

I have make 100 test for sure, I created a 1d4 from a mesh, and from a math function, cut the top after having subdivide all top parts.

My issue seems to be the numbers each time I print after exporting the stl file, the the numbers are reversed but not the letter, I even try other fonts such as arial black, but nothing seem to change.

I check with 3d tool all ok, Its print pretty well, but like I said the number are always reversed. I'm on my last test reverse the number before apply boolean modifier and I'm waiting to see if it will work, but when I check in slicer file its seem to go well.

But like I said On the model everything seem fine but print number reverse , even when I switch side for the wrong side on model on slicer it seem so go right side of dice.

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on your exact workflow when you export your object ? It's possible that the boolean objects you are using to cut the holes are still selected while exporting

Comment: when you say "reverse", do you mean that the numbers are indented into the die and you would like them to protude outside of the die ?

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Comment: Hi , Thank again for respond, What is blend file ? and I got other image for better understanding if its help!

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=d4ZM10vK" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/d4ZM10vK/)

Comment: When you say reverse do you mean you want to extrude the text outward? Have you tried Prusaslicer? Do you have the original blender file before you applied the numbers with the modifier, If so upload that file (before applying any modifiers)? Or Is this an STL file that you imported into blender?